Export the result of max_flow_min_cost from Networkx into csv file
I use max_flow_min_cost from Networkx and I can't export the result of the algoritm
When I use write_edgelist, I get, in the csv file, :
2 4 {}
where 2 and 4 are the nodes
instead of
2 4 8
where 8 is the value between the nodes 2 and 4
Thanks
Christophe

Your question lacks clarity. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and in particular https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. The result of max_flow_min_cost is a dictionary (of dictionaries), so how do you apply write_edgelist to it? And why would that write a CSV?

If you run the example code provided in the documentation you will see that the max_flow_min_cost() method returns a dictionary of the form {node1: {node2: value1, node3: value2, ... }, ...}. Your edges would be <node1, node2, value1>, <node1, node3, value2> and so on. So you need to first unpack this dictionary of dictionaries into edgelist form so that you can write to a file. Maybe something like this:
mincostFlow = nx.max_flow_min_cost(graph, source, sink)
edgelist = pandas.DataFrame([[u,v, mincostFlow[u][v]] for u in mincostFlow for v in mincostFlow[u]], columns = ['node1', 'node2', 'value'])
edgelist.to_csv(file) #open a file first

write_edgelist() would not work here since it takes as input a networkx Graph object, and the return type of man_flow_min_cost is not Graph.
